# Pdf generating using iText on a primefaces project

Tags: servlets, pdf, itext

I'm trying to allow user to download a generated pdf by clicking a button but I don't know where is the problem in my code

I have a servlet

```
public class PdfGeneratorServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    super.doGet(req, response); 
    try {
         System.out.println("yes this is the servlet pdfgenerator");
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutputStream =
             new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Create PDF represented by document and write
        // send outout to our output stream.  
        // Document has the size and margins.

        Document document = 
                  new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfOutputStream);

        // PDF metadata.  Please see Document class
        // documentation to see more metadata that
        // you can use.

        document.addTitle("Servlet sample");
        document.addAuthor("The Kahimyang Project");

        document.open();

        // Write a paragraph using with font.
        document.add(new Paragraph("PDF Writer",
            FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 20)));

        // Paragraphs can contains, tables, images,
        // text, chuck of text, etc.

        Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
        Chunk text = new Chunk("Content to write",
            FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12));

        paragraph1.add(text);

        // the image url below is a sample image

        Image image =
                Image.getInstance(
                new URL("http://kahimyang.info/kauswagan/images/bribe-no.png"));

        // this would enable succedding text in the same
        // paragraph to wrap around the righ-aligned 
        // image

        image.setAlignment(Image.RIGHT | Image.TEXTWRAP);

        // Insert image to the same paragraph where we 
        // have our text above.
        paragraph1.add(image);

        // add the paragraph to our document
        document.add(paragraph1);


        Chunk hyperlink = new Chunk("The Kahimyang Project",
                FontFactory.getFont(
                       FontFactory.TIMES, 12, Font.UNDERLINE));

        // We add a hyperlink to chunk of text
        // The link below is a sample link.

        hyperlink.setAction(
                new PdfAction(new URL("http://kahimyang.info")));
        Paragraph paragraph2 = 
             new Paragraph("More text for your document.");

        // Add text with hyperlink to paragraph

        paragraph2.add(hyperlink);
        document.add(paragraph2);


        document.close();


        // Header
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(pdfOutputStream.size());

        // Write the PDF
        ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = 
                            response.getOutputStream();
        responseOutputStream.write(pdfOutputStream.toByteArray());
        responseOutputStream.flush();
        responseOutputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


}

   @Override
   public String getServletInfo() {
    return "My PDF Generator";
   }
}
```

and my button in xhtml  is

`<h:outputLink value="pdf/khalid">
            <h:outputText value="Generate PDF" />
</h:outputLink>`

and my servlet Mapping in web.xml

```
<!-- PDF Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PdfGenerator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.project.servlets.PdfGeneratorServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PdfGenerator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pdf/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**the problem** is when I click on the link there is no file download but a redirection to a 405 page 
[image]

**UPDATE**

when I delete the line `super.doGet(req, response);` from the Servlet this redirect me to a blank page and no pdf is downloading.

Comment: You posted a localized message. What does it mean? Does it mean something like, "The requested method GET is not allowed/supported for the URL "xxx""

Comment: Sorry,yes this is the meaning of the message

Comment: What media type does it show, when the request is completed (on the developer tool - Google Chrome)? Is it `application/pdf` or just `text/html`? Is the `doGet()` method invoked properly and consequently you see the message, "*yes this is the servlet pdfgenerator*" on the server terminal (log)?

Comment: yes i can see the log "yes this is the servlet pdfgenerator"  and Google Chrome mention that is "text/plain"

Comment: Does adding this line `response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=yourPDFFileName.pdf");` after (or before) this line in your code `response.setContentType("application/pdf");` make a difference (it is just to show the download dialog)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `super.doGet`: that's what is throwing the "GET not supported" error.  The default implementation of `doGet` (i.e. the one defined in `HttpServlet` which is the `super` class here, is to print the message that GET is undefined.  Because by default, you haven't defined it yet (i.e. not overloaded the `doGet` method).  So when you call `super.doGet` its filling the `response` with the 405 headers.  You don't want the super class to run its default method; you only want your overloaded method to run.

After you've called `super.doGet` the rest of your function is wrapped in a `try` with an empty `catch`.  I think probably, if you were to output the error there to a log it would be something like "response headers already set" because the call to `super.doGet` already set the headers to content-type HTML, status 405, etc. so your attempt to change the content-type to PDF is going to throw an error there.

As to the rest of your problem, you have not set enough headers. Namely, you are missing these two:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=whatever.pdf");
```

And rather than doing:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
...
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfOutputStream);
...
//set headers
ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
responseOutputStream.write(pdfOutputStream.toByteArray());
responseOutputStream.flush();
responseOutputStream.close();
```

I would advise just passing the servlet response outputstream directly into the `getInstance` method of the PDF writer:

```
//set headers
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()));
...
```

(You probably also want to save the writer into a variable `PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(....);`) and maybe do something with it.

That way you aren't writing to a buffer, reading from the buffer, and finally writing to the response.  It just writes the PDF to the response directly instead.  And there's no need to manually flush or close the response buffer. Doing it this way does mean you can no longer set the content length header, but that one is not necessary anyway and will cause problems if you get it wrong.

Also, if you set the headers first, at the very top, then it will be locked in to serving the response as PDF even if it encounters an error and doesn't actually build a valid PDF, so that rather than ending up with a blank page, in the event of an error, you'll end up with a blank (i.e. corrupt) PDF.  So at least the PDF application will open. It will just open with an error like "Could not open this PDF; it may be corrupt."

Comment: Great answer, however I have one comment: there is a reason why people write the PDF bytes to memory first. Some browsers can't deal with PDF very well. They read data in blocks of a fixed size, adding meaningless bytes at the end of the PDF file if its size isn't a multiple of the fixed size. The only way to work around this, is by adding a header with the file size `response.setContentLength(pdfOutputStream.size());`. The only way to know the file size, is to create the PDF in memory first.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I do recall that issue with IE6.